# Problemas con cursores en PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, cursor

Estas son las tablas:

```sql
SQL> DESC pais;

Name                                      Null?    Type                        
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
COD_PAIS                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
NOMBRE                                             VARCHAR2(30)                
CAPITAL                                            VARCHAR2(20)                
EXTENSION                                          NUMBER(10)                  
MONEDA                                             VARCHAR2(20)                
NUM_HAB                                            NUMBER(10)                  
PIB                                                NUMBER(20,2)                
CONTINENTE                                         VARCHAR2(20)                
CASCOS                                             CHAR(1)                     
SQL> DESC pertenece_a;

Name                                      Null?    Type                        
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
COD_ORGANIZACION                          NOT NULL NUMBER(10)                  
COD_PAIS                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
SQL> DESC organizacion;

Name                                      Null?    Type                        
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
COD_ORGANIZACION                          NOT NULL NUMBER(10)                  
NOMBRE                                             VARCHAR2(80)                
SIGLAS                                             VARCHAR2(6)
```

Necesito cambiar el valor **CASCOS** a **S** si las **SIGLAS** son **ONU**. Si no, tienen que cambiar **N**. Este es mi código. SQL Developer no informa de ningún error, sin embargo no se está produciendo el cambio del cursor C1.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT cascos FROM pais P, organizacion O, pertenece_a PE WHERE P.cod_pais=PE.cod_pais AND O.cod_organizacion=PE.cod_organizacion AND O.siglas='ONU' FOR UPDATE;
    CURSOR C2 IS SELECT cascos FROM pais WHERE cascos IS NULL FOR UPDATE;
    registro1 C1%ROWTYPE;
    registro2 C2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    IF NOT C1%ISOPEN THEN
            OPEN C1;
    END IF;
    IF NOT C2%ISOPEN THEN
            OPEN C2;
    END IF;
    LOOP
        FETCH C1 INTO registro1;
        EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE pais SET cascos='S' WHERE CURRENT OF C1;
    END LOOP;
    LOOP
        FETCH C2 INTO registro2;
        EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
        UPDATE pais SET cascos='N' WHERE CURRENT OF C2;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
    CLOSE C2;
END;
/
SELECT * FROM pais WHERE cascos='S';
```

La salida del SQL Developer solo dice:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

no rows selected
```

¿Cuál podría ser el error? Un pais puede pertener a más de una organización. ¿Puede ser ese el problema?¿No se están recorriendo correctamente las tablas?
Gracias.

Comment: Traduce por favor pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Sorry :) No me dí cuenta. Traducida